# VB.Net write and read DataTable to/from XML-file

Tags: vb.net, datatable, xml

I'm trying to write a DataTable to an XML-file and read afterwards the data from the XML-file to another DataTable with the following VB.Net code, I'm getting the error "DataTable does not support schema inference from Xml.":

```
dt1.WriteXml(fileName:=xf, writeHierarchy:=True)  
Dim dt2 = New Data.DataTable(dt1.TableName)  
dt2 = ds.Tables(0)  
dt2.ReadXml(fileName:=xf)
```

I could solve my problem with read the file into a DataSet, but I would like to understand the difference:

```
Dim ds = New Data.DataSet()  
ds.ReadXml(fileName:=xf)  
Dim dt2 = ds.Tables(0)
```

Could anybody tell me?

Comment: For some reason DataTable needs the columns set up ahead of time in order to read an xml file

Answer (score 2):

I know this question asked long time ago, but I had same problem few days ago.

You have to set `TableName` for `DataTable` before exporting (writing `xml`).

Example :

```
    dt1.TableName = "MyDataTable"
    dt1.WriteXmlSchema(Application.StartupPath + "\test_sh.xml", True)
    dt1.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath + "\test_dt.xml", True)
```

And, for read (import from `xml`) back in new `DataTable` :

```
    dt2 = New DataTable
    dt2.ReadXmlSchema(Application.StartupPath + "\test_sh.xml")
    dt2.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\test_dt.xml")
```

And then populate Your `GridView` or what else You need.

`TableName` for `dt2` will be automatically pulled from schema file (`test_sh.xml`). In this case `MyDataTable`, like was set in `dt1.TableName`.

It's *important* to save `schema`, too, or You can't read `xml` back in table.